# How can i put criteria for my subclass

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

here is the hierarchy of the classes
ControlTransaction.gridRows.recordstatus

I want ControlTransaction and in that ControlTransaction I want gridRows only which is having recordstuas 1 
here recordstuas is boolean.

How can i implement the same.?

```
startReadOperation();
Criteria criteriaCtrl = session.createCriteria(ControlTransaction.class);
criteriaCtrl.add(Restrictions.eq("documentId", doc.getId()));
addRecordStatusCriteria(criteriaCtrl);
criteriaCtrl.createAlias("gridRows", "cg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
startReadOperation();
Criteria criteriaCtrl = session.createCriteria(ControlTransaction.class);
criteriaCtrl.add(Restrictions.eq("documentId", doc.getId())).createCriteria("gridRows").add(Restrictions.eq("recordstatus", true));
```

you can create nested criteria as many level as you want.